# Screen Suddenly Turns Black

Tags: iphone, ios

While using my app, the screen sometimes suddenly and inexplicably turns black. The screen is still powered, and if I play with the volume controls, the volume indicator shows just fine.

The only way to resolve this is to press the home button, at which point I see the following message in my log:

> SpringBoard[15] : Failed to snapshot WaveDeck

When I then open the app again, it's fine.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I like the 'shed some light' joke, +1.

Comment: But seriously now, is your app OpenGL, storyboard, etc?

Comment: Is your app WaveDeck, or do you have the WaveDeck app installed?

Comment: It's our app - we just solved this issue, and I asked Shahar (our excellent lead developer) to put up an answer here. Watch this space :)

Answer (score 2):

Update from the WaveDeck front:

We've used `applicationDidEnterBackground` in the app's delegate in a bad way: asking all the background operations to finish up using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` and keeping the main runloop running inside `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

That way the method of `applicationDidEnterBackground` came to an end only after finishing all background operations, whether the app became active again or not.

So apparently the OS could not 'snapshot' the app correctly and would put on a black screen some time after returning from background state - when the delegate function of `applicationDidEnterBackground` ended.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a similar issue. Put the long time save operation in next runloop, so applicationDidEnterBackground return immediately, the system's snapshot mechanism works correctly.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // don't block ios's snapshoting, avoid screen suddenly turns black
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(saveAppState) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(saveAppState) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
- (void)saveAppState
{
    [self longtimeSave];
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(saveAppState) object:nil];
}
```